# Maven: Release:perform fails, but deploy works.

Tags: maven, deployment, amazon-s3, release

My pom file looks like this :

```
    <distributionManagement>
            <repository>
              <id>maven-s3-release-repo</id>
              <name>S3 Release Repository</name>
              <!-- http://bigpetstore.s3.amazonaws.com/maven/ -->
              <url>s3://bigpetstore/maven</url>
            </repository>
    </distributionManagement>
```

When I run , "mvn deploy", I get my project published to the correct repository.

However, if I run "release:prepare" followed by "release:perform", I get the following error:

```
[INFO] [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-  
plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project BigPetStorePro: Deployment failed: 
repository element was not specified in the POM inside distributionManagement element or 
in -DaltDeploymentRepository=id::layout::url parameter -> [Help 1]
```

So, my question is:  Why is it that "mvn deploy" is able to easily deploy my contents, however, mvn release:prepare fails to see the contents of the distributionManagement?

Clearly, the  tag is present.

Comment: Are there any profiles active that could replace this values?

Comment: Do you have right credentials to S3 ?